# Azure Storage Account File Versions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to back up our Azure File Storage shares (and preferably blobs too). I have set up a nightly automation task to use AzCopy to replicate the storage account to another one. However, this doesn't give us the granularity of historical backups that we need (eg restoring a file or folder from 2 weeks ago). I've been thinking about pushing the contents of the storage account to an S3 bucket which does of course support versioning...but I was hoping someone has already solved this within the bounds of Azure...

Answer (score 2):

For this there are snapshots available.
https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-7-snapshots/

With AzCopy you can add the snapshot option.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/04/01/azcopy-using-cross-account-copy-blob.aspx

Here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh488361.aspx) you can see how you can generate the url to a specific version of a file

edit after questions:

For files something like this: AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount1.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/ /Dest:https://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/ /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /S

A good option would be to copy to a account which you generate every day like project-backups20160201 
Here you can find the code to generate a storage account and get the key:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh264518.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460785.aspx

that way you can easily find the correct file and you can also delete old backups in an easy way without the hassle of searching the correct snapshot.

If you don't mind paying for the service this could be a good solution. https://www.cherrysafe.com/Home/Features#storageBackup

Comment: But can I snapshot Azure File Storage files or shares?

Comment: If you look here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-file-storage-now-generally-available/ you can see there is no official way to achieve snapshotting yet. Seeing with AZCopy you have to specify the file in the File storage you could copy it to a normal blob file and use the snapshotting feature there.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your last point...can you elaborate?

Comment: Something like this : AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount1.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/ /Dest:https://myaccount2.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/ /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /S

Comment: I changed the post to elaborate.